# Get Console output of jenkins build in jTextArea

Tags: java, user-interface, jenkins, console, jtextarea

I have written a script in java which i am using to trigger the build in jenkins by passing the URL of the jenkins job. Now, i want to append the console output generated during the build in my jTextArea as i am designing a UI in java for triggering the build and getting the build report or output generated from console in UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This the way how i solved my problem by passing the job xml file as URL and then using parser to get the information written on xml file.

```
  URL obj = new URL(String url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(conn.getInputStream());
```